# Searching for a specific string entered by user in CSV file?

Tags: java, android, csv

Currently, I am trying to create a mobile application in Android Studio which allows the user to enter an ISBN number and when the search button is clicked, it will then search a CSV in the raw folder and return results of that ISBN query. This CSV file includes all other information which is associated with that number separated by commas. Currently its returns all results of the CSV file ordered into edit text fields on the user interface. How can I change my code to only return the specific result which I want?

This is the readFile class:

```
public class readFile {


 InputStream inputStream;

    public readFile(InputStream inputStream){
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public List<String[]> read(){
        List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String csvLine;
            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
                resultList.add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

The itemArrayAdapter class:

```
public class ItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {


private List<String[]> scoreList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    static class ItemViewHolder {
        EditText title, publicationPlace,publicationDate,edition,author;
    }

    public ItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String[] object) {
        scoreList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.scoreList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getItem(int index) {
        return this.scoreList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.publicationDate = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.publicationDate);
            viewHolder.publicationPlace = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.publicationPlace);
            viewHolder.edition = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.edition);
            viewHolder.author = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.authors);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        String[] isbn = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.title.setText(isbn[1]);
        viewHolder.publicationDate.setText(isbn[2]);
        viewHolder.publicationPlace.setText(isbn[3]);
        viewHolder.edition.setText(isbn[4]);
        viewHolder.author.setText(isbn[5]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give us code snippets and what you tried already...

Answer (score 0):

[...code...]

```
String[] row = csvLine.split(",");

// Add the check as shown here:
for ( int col = 0; col < row.length; col++ ) {    // this could be avoided
    if ( row[col].compareTo(ISBN_string) == 0 )
       resultList.add(row);
}
// Maby if you know the column no. you can get away without the iteration

// resultList.add(row);  <-- this is now obsolete
```

[...more code...]

Comment: Please give a description of the error while answering( if necessary ), and avoid lines like [...code...]